# How to store data in wampserver

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, android-studio

```
public class activityresult2 extends Activity {

static public String txtOrder ="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activityresult2);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String strfnq = bundle.getString("Noodle quantity");
    String strfrq = bundle.getString("Rice quantity");
    String strfsq = bundle.getString("Fish quantity");
    String stricq = bundle.getString("Iced tea");
    Integer strsum = bundle.getInt("sum");

    boolean addNingc = bundle.getBoolean("ANI");
    boolean addRingc = bundle.getBoolean("ARI");
    boolean addFingc = bundle.getBoolean("AFI");
    boolean addTingc = bundle.getBoolean("AIT");
    boolean addmoneyc = bundle.getBoolean("AMY");

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();

    int sum = mIntent.getIntExtra("sum",strsum);
    TextView costtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.costtext);
    costtext.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

    TextView foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    foodorders.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Quantity"));

    String addNdlThing = "";
    if (addNingc) { 
        addNdlThing = " with addition of ingredients";
    }

    String addRlThing = "";
    if (addRingc) {
        addRlThing = " with addition of ingredients";
    }

    String addSlThing = "";
    if ( addFingc) {
        addSlThing = " with addition of ingredients";
    }

     String addTeac = "";
    if ( addTingc ) {
        addTeac = " with addition of ingredients";
    }

    foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    if(strfnq.equals("") && strfrq.equals("") && strfsq.equals("")&& stricq.equals("")){
        txtOrder = "Sorry, You've not ordered any thing , please return to previous menu to order";
    }else if (!strfnq.equals("") && !strfrq.equals("") && !strfsq.equals("")&& stricq.equals("")) {
        txtOrder = "Thank you , You've ordered\n" + strfnq + " fried noodle" + addNdlThing +" and\n"+ strfrq
                + " fried rice" + addRlThing +" and\n" + strfsq + " Steam fish " + addSlThing + "and\n" + stricq + " Steam fish " + addTeac;
    } else {
        txtOrder = "Thank you , You've ordered\n";
        if(!strfnq.equals("")){
            txtOrder = txtOrder + strfnq + " fried noodle" + addNdlThing;
        }
        if(!strfrq.equals("")){
            txtOrder = txtOrder + strfrq + " fried rice" + addRlThing;
        }
        if(!strfsq.equals("")){
            txtOrder = txtOrder + strfsq + " Steam fish" + addSlThing;
        }
        if(!stricq.equals("")){
            txtOrder = txtOrder + stricq + " Iced Tea"+ addTeac;
        }
    }
    foodorders.setText(txtOrder);
}
```

after i select my food in the previous page which is **activityresult1** , my food is displayed in this page(**activityresult2**) , under *Textview* **foodorders**.... If i press a button on this page ,  i want all the items showed at **foododers** to be stored in my wampserver database which is mysql database , do anyone knows how to do that

Comment: You can not connect mysql server using android sdk. You must create server side script that manage to store data in mysql database. You can send data to script using http connection.

Comment: @USKMobility and do you know how to do that , if yes please drop me a email at vyshunavi95@yahoo.com

Comment: Wait wait wait. Do you want the database to necessarily be on the internet or just inside the android app? Android has SQLite for storing foodorders and such for on-device data only. If you wish to connect to an online database, it will be trickier but you can set up a website with WAMP and parse data off of it with httpurlconnect in android.

Comment: @ScriptKitty i can already register an account and store the account details inside it the WAMP , but now i want to store other information , but i dont know how to add it in , please drop me a email

Comment: Is the WAMP online or on localhost?

Comment: @ScriptKitty local host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not connect mysql server directly from android app. You must create server side script that manage to store data in mysql database. You can send data to script using http connection. If you are using PHP, these great tutorials help you.

[Android - PHP/MYSQL Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm)

[How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

First configure wamp server in localhost environment. In order to configure wamp 
1) get ipaddress of your machine
2) click on putonline button in wamp server.
3) write a php script to store data in mysql.
4) call that php script from your mobile like(http://192.168.0.5/package name/php file name)

check this link: http://androidprogramz.blogspot.in/2012/07/connect-mysql-database-from-android.html

Comment: i already did that, i just want to add , but i dont know how to add it in my database please drop me a email at vyshunavi95@yahoo.com

Comment: hi could you pelase help me